# Is reflooding a word?

Tags: word-usage

Example sentence:

> Eri hugged him back, tears reflooding.

The word appears in some online dictionaries, however every word processor underlines it with a red line.

Is it safe to use this word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually difficult to say exactly "what is an English word" because English lets you add prefixes and suffixes to a root word to make new ones.  *Flood* is a word, and *re* is a prefix meaning "again", so ***reflood* sounds like a perfectly valid word to me, meaning "flood again."**

The reason that words like this don't necessarily show up in dictionaries is because the number of possible words that you can make is huge:

- flood = to fill with water
- reflood = to fill with water again
- refloodable = capable of being filled with water again
- unrefloodable = not capable of being filled with water again
- unrefloodability = state of not being capable of being filled with water again
- antiunrefloodability = against the state of not being capable of being filled with water again
  etc.

Should a dictionary include every single possible word that you can make?  Even if it were possible, it might not be useful.  So dictionaries tend to be limited to the more "standard" words.

**However**, the way you use it in your example sentence doesn't sound right to me.  [*to flood*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flood) can be either intransitive or transitive:

- The valley flooded (*the valley became filled with water*)
- Jose flooded the valley (*Jose filled the valley with water*)

When you use it intransitively, it means "the subject became filled with water".  So "tears reflooded" means...tears became filled with water again?  That doesn't make sense.  It would make more sense to say "tears reflooded" *something else*, like "tears reflooded his eyes", because the tears are doing the filling of something else.  (Thanks to ColleenV for that example!)

Comment: I disagree English lets you arbitrarily create new words like you suggest.  Yes, re as a prefix can mean again, but not always.  Take record, for example.  It doesn't me you corded again.  And while people might figure it out based on the re prefix, the real test is whether a word is in common usage.  I think most English speakers would look at you funny if you said reflood to them (and accordingly, my spell checker is flagging it).

Comment: I didn't say "arbitrarily".  There are, after all, rules about how you can add these things.  Also, "re" is not always a prefix, as you point out, but I'm not sure what that has to do with the case of "re-flood", and you can certainly make "re-record".

Comment: My point is I don't think reflood is a word, but you suggest it is because you make it sound like you can just add a "re" in front of anything you want.  That's how I read your answer, at least, given all the other prefixes you add to "flood" (all of which would cause people to look at you funny, IMO).